# Generic TypeCode Type Checking?

Tags: c#, generics

Should I avoid type checking with generics? Not using traditional type checking comparisons(`myvar is int`), but rather using the type's typecode.

Using generics, with type checking allows you to create a single method without parameters that supports the tasks of regular overloaded methods. This is a problem with parameter-less methods, they cannot be overloaded.

```
// "Buffer" is the byte[] while "Peek" is the read/write position. Then Align" is the alignment size in bytes of the buffer.
public type Read<type>() {
    switch( Type.GetTypeCode( typeof( type ) ) ) {
        case System.TypeCode.Boolean:
            bool bool_val = ( Buff[ Peek ] > 0 );
            Peek = ( ++Peek + ( Align - 1 ) ) & ~( Align - 1 );
            return (type)(object)bool_val;
        case System.TypeCode.Byte:
            byte byte_val = Buff[ Peek ];
            Peek = ( ++Peek + ( Align - 1 ) ) & ~( Align - 1 );
            return (type)(object)byte_val;
        case TypeCode.Ushort:
            ushort ushort_val = (ushort)( Buff[ Peek ] | ( Buff[ Peek + 1 ] << 8 ) );
            Peek += 2;
            Peek = ( Peek + ( Align - 1 ) ) & ~( Align - 1 );
            return (type)(object)ushort_val;
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems like the only way to achieve a form of overloading with parameter-less methods. Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Whether something is good or bad practice is often very contextual. Can you give some more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Good point. I've got a buffer class I'm writing for a networking system. I need both read/write methods of several types. However this isn't easily done for read-methods since they can't be overloaded. Which forces me to either use generic type checking or multiple individualized methods--which is also kind f bad from a design standpoint. However you can apply this to most situations where you've got a single multi-functional type of method that needs generic control.

Comment: Can you give examples of the respective cases for `Boolean` and `Byte`? As it stands right now, I don't even see the need to make this method generic (as opposed to passing the `Type` as a regular argument). If the method doesn't really need to be generic - but instead is simply used as a call spot for hard-coded specialized cases -, then no, it's not bad practice to do what you're doing (since there is no other way to achieve it). But, as I said, some more details in the method body would make it easier to see what you have in mind.

Comment: Done, changed the OP. Yeah, I have to hard code specialize cases since reading different types out of the buffer requires different cases.

Comment: Are you sure this can't be written as generic code? For example, `Peek` seems to be incremented by the size of `type` (`sizeof(type)` or `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(type))`), then some function of `Align`. `Align` sounds like it is some function of the size. Getting the `bool_val`, `byte_val`, `ushort_val` generically is a bit tricky to get right, but I think you can create a `MemoryStream` at the current position of the `Buffer` and for a length equal to the size of `type`, then use the `Marshal` class to instantiate a struct from that (since you already have the memory layout in the buffer).

Comment: Yeah, it's not easy, especially dealing with dynamic length--null terminated--strings. I could generalize a few things, however strings and floats will deviate from that generalization since they're handled differently.

Comment: I've attempted to provide an outline for a generic approach for structs. If you need to handle strings as well, then you'll definitely have to provide explicit specializations, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code generic with something like this:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
var subBuffer = new byte[size];
Array.Copy(Buff, Peek, subBuffer, 0, size);
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(subBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var ptr = handle.ToIntPtr();
var val = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
ptr.Free();
Peek += size;
Peek = ( Peek + ( Align - 1 ) ) & ~( Align - 1 );
return val;
```

However, if this suffers from performance issues for your use case, then providing hard-coded specialized versions probably isn't a bad way to do it, since there aren't any obvious alternatives.